# Using Function.prototype.call as a callback

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I tried the following in the Google Chrome console:

```
> function t1(f) { return f(1); }
> function t2() { return this+1; }
> t1(t2.call)
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Why does this not work? Is there a way to define a function in lieu of Function.prototype.call that would work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because when you're passing `t2.call`, you're actually just passing `.call`. In other words, it doesn't remember the object from which it was passed.

---

To accomplish what you wanted, you can use `.bind()`.

```
t1(t2.call.bind(t2))
```

This binds the `t2` function as the `this` value of `.call`, which means you'll be calling `.call` as though you had done this:

```
t2.call
```

...which is what you wanted.

---

The `.bind` method is not supported in IE8 and lower, as well as some other older browsers, but you can implement a mostly complete shim in those cases.

---

FYI, if you need this a lot, you could bind `.call` as the calling context of `.bind` to shorten it a bit.

```
var callBind = Function.prototype.bind.bind(Function.prototype.call);
```

So now you have a `.bind()` function with `.call()` bound as its calling context. When you invoke it, it will be as if you were doing this:

```
.call.bind(/* the function */)
```

So `callBind()` will return a function with `the function` bound as the calling context of `.call`, just like we did above. So you'd use it like this:

```
t1(callBind(t2))
```

Comment: "It doesn't work because when you're passing t2.call, you're actually just passing .call. In other words, it doesn't remember the object from which it was passed."

Could you explain this a bit more if possible? I don't quite get why it doesn't remember the object.

Comment: @Ray: `.call` is just a property on an object. The only relationship between the object and the function is that the function is assigned to the property. When you pass `t1.call` to another function, you're *retrieving* the function from the `t1` object, but only passing the function, not the object. It would be like if I handed you something, and you took it somewhere. The relationship between myself and that thing is broken once I let go, and that thing has no connection back to me.

Comment: Ahh ok I think I get it. It's like with a regular object/propery say `o ={name: "foo"}`. Then you call `f(o.name)` it's just that property `.name` that's sent with no attachment/reference to `o` anymore... yeah?

Answer (score 2):

Why do things the hard way? Can't you just send over the callback function `t2` to `t1` and use `call()` inside `t1`?

```
function t1(f) { 
    return f.call(1); 
}

function t2() { 
    return this+1; 
}

t1(t2);
```

Comment: Hmm, it was really more for personal edification than anything else. Thanks for the suggestion though.